# How to show ICredentialProviderCredentialv2 on more than one User tile on the other user tile

Tags: c, authentication, com, credentials, credential-providers

I'm trying to develop a Credentialprovider v2. I'm experimenting around with the samplecredentialproviderv2 provided by Microsoft.After installing the redistributable 2013 and compiling for the right architecture, I'd registered it and it worked.

My Problem is, it works only on the first shown user tile. If I enumerate more than one usertile, it is either shown in only one user tile, or I became an error and destroyed my Logon UI.

I know the question is quite similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29603940/displaying-a-v2-credential-provider-on-other-user-tile). Here I can say I've tried the solution stated in the mentioned Microsoft document. There is a function which indicates if the "other user" tile is shown and this function works quite good. The only thing is, the else if won't work, because if you get a legit tile getSid won't reach the else if. So if you return in getSid a null sid and hr_false the credentialprovider is shown the other user tile, but in this case not shown everywhere else. If this solution is hard coded.
I've tried to create more than one ICredentialProviderCredential, so that I have a list of interfaces, but it doesn't worked.

The document, which is provided [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=253508), says the following:
"•  v2 credential providers must implement the ICredentialProviderCredential2 interface and return a valid SID on the GetUserSID function. This tells Windows which user(s) the provider should be associated with."

My problem is, how to return more than one Sid in the GetUserSid function.
It would be great if you can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ICredentialProvider::GetCredentialCount() you return the number of credential tiles (one per user) that your credential provider will supply (the credential provider can learn how many users there 'are' from the user array given to SetUserArray() ).  Return a different ICredentialProviderCredential2 instance in response to each call logon makes to your ICredentialProvider::GetCredentialAt(), and from each of these instances return a different SID in response to GetUserSID(). Each of your credentials should then be associated with a different user at logon.

Comment: Thank you Phil, it seems obvious after I checked my log. So I mark it as solved.

Comment: @Khalidjian I do have exactly the same problem: My CP v2 is only showing for the Local Administrator Account. Could you please provide the code you implemented with help as I'm quite new to C++? Many Thanks

Comment: @StehtimSchilf I'm sorry I can't provide example code, because the project developed too far away from the pure credential provider, so I'm going to fear it will be very confusing, if I post example code.

Comment: @StehtimSchilf I'm going to give you a hint in your provider header is a private member of type "CSampleCredential" if you use the microsoft example. I changed it to: `std::vector<CSampleCredential>   _pCredentialVector;    // SampleV2Credential` So you can create a Credential for each shown user.