# Windows Credential Provider - Change User name Label on new Tile

Tags: c++, remote-desktop, credential-providers, windows-credential-provider, windows-logon

I use my credential provider for RDP login on server windows.

I customize `UpdateRemoteCredential` to transport login data like as username and password. and I can login successfully by the user and pass:

```
pcpcsOut->ulAuthenticationPackage = pcpcsIn->ulAuthenticationPackage;
pcpcsOut->cbSerialization = pcpcsIn->cbSerialization;
pcpcsOut->rgbSerialization = pcpcsIn->rgbSerialization;
pcpcsOut->clsidCredentialProvider = CLSID_CSamanV2Provider;

if (pcpcsOut->cbSerialization > 0 && (pcpcsOut->rgbSerialization = static_cast<BYTE*>(CoTaskMemAlloc(pcpcsIn->cbSerialization))) != nullptr)
{
    CopyMemory(pcpcsOut->rgbSerialization, pcpcsIn->rgbSerialization, pcpcsIn->cbSerialization);

    return S_OK;
}
```

After do this, I create a new Initialize function to create a new tile and login auto.

```
_rgpCredentials[0]->Initialize(_cpus, s_rgCredProvFieldDescriptors, s_rgFieldStateNormalPairs, _dwCredUIFlags, wszDomain, wszUsername, wszPassword);
```

[image]

like above picture, the tile's title is "other user". How can I change this to user name that logon by rdp?

So, my question is:

If any way to create the new tile for a user (not Other User) on my scenario? or If any way to change the Other User big title on the my tile?

Comment: Have a look at this [Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74641475/3868464).

Comment: I think, I should use from User SID to link the user that it is loging by RDP. But the problem is I have not access to any UserSID. Maybe be a way to create a temporary UserSID for it to show UserName insteade of the Other User.

Comment: I think that you should rely on the User SID to link your Tile with user.

Comment: I was able to get the USERSID and load the associated tile. But the point is that, if the user who logs in to Windows and does not have a key in the Profile List (it is the first time that he logs in to Windows), I will have problems again. I think either I should ignore this or there is a way to add the profile manually.

Comment: AFAIK Credential Provider's responsibility is to authenticate user. The rest of logon process is responsibility of Winlogon.